# Touch Down does not perform action it is supposed to

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to move an auto complete tableview so it's top will touch bottom border of field user is currently typing in.
To do this, I make some calculation, then perform the move on touch down on the corresponding field.

Here are the 3 outlets variables, 2 fields and one table view:

```
@IBOutlet var tableRefresh:UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var countriesFieldVar: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var countriesFieldVar2: UITextField!
```

Here are the variables....

```
var field1YBottomCoordinate = 0
var tableXCenter = 0
var tableYCenter = 0
var field2YBottomCoordinate = 0
var differenceBetweenY =  0
```

....that I set in viewdidload:

```
     field1YBottomCoordinate = Int(CGRectGetMinY(countriesFieldVar.frame))
     tableXCenter = Int(CGRectGetMidX(tableRefresh.frame))
     tableYCenter = Int(CGRectGetMidY(tableRefresh.frame))

     field2YBottomCoordinate = Int(CGRectGetMinY(countriesFieldVar2.frame))
     differenceBetweenY =  Int(field2YBottomCoordinate - field1YBottomCoordinate) + 1
```

Then, on touch down on countriesFieldVar2, I perform this to move tableRefresh at desired location:

```
@IBAction func coutriesField2SetSelect(sender: AnyObject) {
    tableRefresh.center = CGPoint(x:tableXCenter, y: (tableYCenter + differenceBetweenY))
}
```

Problem is that on first touch on the countriesFieldVar2 field, nothing happens. Or to be correct, I briefly see the table blink to desired location while keyboard moves up, then the table moves back right back where it was. It is only on second touch down in the field that I get the desired move. Why is that ? (please use swift)

Comment: Probably because iOS8 still needs some work done on it.

Comment: do you know an alternative so I can get correct move of the view on first touchdown as it is supposed to happen ?

Comment: I sometimes add a timer and a bool to redo the touches as a go around?

Comment: adding a timer as you suggest forced the view to position correctly. Actually, this was a great, simple fix and saved me lots of trouble finding other way to implement this. If you want to a answer this post i'll pick it up as solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that has worked to force retry with a timer and a bool

```
aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(tryAgain) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)tryAgain{
if (!checkBool){
[self buttonPressed:];
}
}


-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id) sender{
//First fill in code here
checkBool = YES;
[aTimer invalidate];
}
```